# Does xjc's episode mechanism work with include instead of import?

Tags: xml, xsd, xjc

I am trying to use the *xjc* [separate compilation mechanism](http://weblogs.java.net/blog/kohsuke/archive/2006/09/separate_compil.html).

I first compile an XML schema and bundle the resulting class files along with the episode in a jar file. Then I try to compile another schema that refers to the previous one, but although I follow the steps depicted in the documentation (i.e. I specify the first jar file as last argument in the invocation to *xjc* for the second schema), I don't manage to make *xjc* use the classes from another jar file, it keeps generating again the classes.

As my schemas refer to the same namespaces, I use [xs:include](http://www.w3schools.com/schema/el_include.asp) instead of [xs:import](http://www.w3schools.com/schema/el_import.asp) and I suspect this might be the problem.

Does *xjc* separate compilation mechanism support xs:include ?

(my environment consists of: xjc 2.1.10, java 1.6.0_24, SuSE Linux).